# Return value of argument from VBS to Visual Studio Form

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vbscript

Is there a way to call VBS from Visual Studio form, and after the VBS code finished running, then gives back the argument value from VBS to a textbox on the Visual Studio From?

VBS:

```
arg = "TEST STRING"
```

Visual Studio:

```
strcommand2 = ("wscript ""C:\User\test.vbs""")
Shell(strcommand2, AppWinStyle.MinimizedNoFocus, True, 1800000)
TextBox1.Text = arg???
```

Here the textbox value should be `TEST STRING`.

Thank you.

Comment: I activated. How should I refer in Visual Studio to the VBS variable?

Comment: You can instantiate hidden explorer window object in VS, find this window in VBS using `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows`, and put the string using `PutProperty` method, then retrieve the string in VS via `GetProperty` and quit the explorer window.

Comment: Thank you. There is no way to give back the value of the argument from VBS to Visual Studio with a single function?